# Git - creating a pretty log using rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

We have started using Git on our continues delivery (CD) project. 
Our DevOps decided that we must have a clean Git log, where every bubble correlates to a technical/user story. In the log, a commit on the master must be a merge commit from a feature branch. The log must not have more than one level (i.e. it should look as if each branch does not overlap with another branch).
For example:

[image]

So far we achieved this goal by creating a local branch, commit to this branch and rebasing with master before merging the branch to master with no-ff.

However, I am not certain that this approach is optimal. It works well most of the time, but when more than a single developer work on the same branch, they can't rebase with master. Therefore, if they need to sync the branch code with some changes pushed to master, they can't (or at least it's much more complicated)

Being accustomed to previous source control systems, I feel that as rebase loses information about the order in which commits really happened, it much harder to understand what's going on.

What is the best practice for working in a team with the constraint above (the log must look as close to the above image as possible)?

What is the big advantage that such log structure gives to whoever in charge of the release in continues delivery system?

Comment: Did you ask the DevOps what the benefits of that history layout are to them? I think that's a fair question to ask, since you'll have to spend **your time** to polish the git history, which eventually adds very little value **to you**.

Comment: I did. They say that it will allow them to see and control what goes to production. While I understand that the log is much more readable, I'm not sure it worth losing the ability to sync with master and to lose the history of the commits.

Comment: You could try using --topo-order on the logs, that will straighten out some of what confuses them. Nothing says you have to lose the real history in your own repos when you construct the fabricated history they're demanding for theirs.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab and others offer a setting called Semi-linear history which will only allow you to merge a merge request if it is a direct descendent of the target branch.

This means you will need to rebase one last time before being able to merge a finished MR/PR. Of course, this will not prevent merging a branch which itself has merge requests in it.

I'd still challenge your DevOps teams workflow. Why can't they use `git log` with `--no-merges`, `--first-parent`, `--date-order`/`--topo-order` or similar to get the commit view they require?